# How can I force make to re-execute commands?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I found out that Make doesn't run commands twice because it prunes files.

E.g. I have a **Makefile**:

```
.PHONY: double_pause
double_pause: pause pause

.PHONY: pause
pause: 
    bash entrypoint.sh pause
```

and

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e +x

_pause() {
    echo "Wait 5s..." 
    sleep 5s
}

case $1 in
    pause) _pause;;
  *) exec "$@";;
esac
```

But when I execute `make double_pause` I get only one pause with one echo. How to force Make run the same command twice by `make double_pause`?

Comment: Make never does the same thing twice (this is one of the reasons to use it). And even the order in which it does things is not as straightforward as you apparently think. Make is not a scripting language and I suspect that what you're trying to do is not for make. Why not using a shell script (from which you can invoke make if needed)? You would get the sequential in-order execution you apparently want, plus the possibility to run the same command twice or more...

Comment: I realize what I suggested shouldn't work as is. Deleting comment.

Comment: The characterization that `make` "prunes files" doesn't sit well with me.  It seems to betray a view of `make` as some kind of exotic script engine, which it is not.  To me, *of course* `make` does not build the same target twice in the same run.  Because once it builds a given target, that target is, for `make`'s purposes, up to date.  It chooses the order in which it builds targets to ensure that that view is consistent with all targets' declared prerequisites.

Comment: The very existence of a `pause` rule is a bit of a red flag --   One of the key concepts of make is that it waits for all dependencies to be built before building a target.   Because of this, there should not be any need to manually pause between targets if you've written the makefile correctly.  (note -- there may be a need to pause between recipe lines, but you shouldn't need to pause between targets...).   If you have a target that runs a recipe in the background, have that recipe output a lock file once it's done, and have the parent target depend on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make` does not build the same target twice during the same run.  This is embedded deeply within its design.  Thus, the simple answer to the title question is "you can't".

It's unclear why you are trying to apply `make` to your task, as opposed to writing it in a programming language. The makefile language is not one, and `make` itself is not a script engine.  It would be much cleaner and easier to update your existing shell script to appropriately handle `double_pause` as an argument (a one-line addition) than to do anything with `make`.

HOWEVER, if you insist on doing it with `make` anyway, then you have at least these alternatives:

1. Do everything directly in the recipe for `double_pause`:

   ```
   double_pause:
           bash entrypoint.sh pause
           bash entrypoint.sh pause
   ```
2. Similar, but re-using the `pause` target via recursive `make`:

   ```
   double_pause:
           $(MAKE) pause
           $(MAKE) pause
   ```